# Finding a node in a tree that appears most frequently in all levels

Tags: python, tree

I recently had a coding quiz that asks me to find a node in a tree that appears most frequently in all levels.

For example,

```
      a
     /  \
   c    a
  / \  / \
 c  a b   c
```

In this tree, `a` should be the answer since it appears in level 0, 1, and 2.

I tried to approach this using level-order traversal, but I was confused how to keep track of in which level the node has appeared.

How can I approach this problem, preferably using Python?

Tree Struct:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = TreeNode(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = TreeNode(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data
```

Comment: How is your tree structured in Python? With dictionaries or class objects?

Comment: Just added in the EDIT.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include your code and describe what does not work.

Comment: By the way it's not possible to replicate the tree you provided in example with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you traverse the tree you use a `dict` to keep track of which level each node type was seen on. This can be achieved by having your keys to be nodes and your values to be sets of levels on which the node was seen.

```
def most_frequent_in_levels(tree):

    counter = {}

    def level_counter(tree, counter, level):
        if tree.data not in counter:
            counter[tree.data] = {level}
        else:
            counter[tree.data].add(level)

        if tree.left:
            level_counter(tree.left, counter, level + 1)

        if tree.right:
            level_counter(tree.right, counter, level + 1)

    level_counter(tree, counter, 0)

    return max(counter.keys(), key=lambda data: len(counter[data]))
```

Here is a working example.

```
tree = TreeNode(data='a')
tree.left, tree.right= TreeNode(data='a'), TreeNode(data='b')
tree.left.left, tree.left.right, tree.right.left = TreeNode(data='c'), TreeNode(data='c'), TreeNode(data='c')

# Which creates the following tree
#
#          a
#         /  \
#       a    b
#      / \  /
#     c  c c 

most_frequent_in_levels(tree) # 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would go about it, this is basically psuedo code and untested

```
countingdict = {}
for tag, element in root:
   if tag not in dict:
         countingdict.update({tag:1})
   else:
         countingdict[tag] += 1
```

You could nest the loop for a many levels as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom version the [Breadth-First-Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search):

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
def bsf(tree):
  d = deque([tree])
  levels = defaultdict(list)
  count = 0
  seen = [tree.data]
  while seen:
     listing = []
     while d:
      val = d.popleft()
      if val:
         levels[count].append(val.data)
         listing.extend([val.right, val.left])
     count += 1 
     if not any(listing):
       break
     d.extend(listing)
  return levels


result = bsf(t1)
frequencies = {i:[b for _, b in result.items() if i in b] for i in [c for h in result.values() for c in h]}
last_result = map(frequencies.items(), key=lambda x:len(x[-1]))[0]
```